# Creating a local connection in Oracle SQL developer 12c

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, localconnection

Not sure if I'm missing anything.
I'm trying to create a local connection in order to create a new user in Oracle SQL developer 12c. (AVOIDING CDB connection)
After browsing for an hour, came across 2 methods.

1. Using connection type as "Local/Bequeath"

Throws following error (Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied)

2. Using connection type as "Basic", Hostname as "localhost", Port as "1521", and Service name as "XEPDB1"

Throws following error (Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor)

Thanks.

Comment: You want the second option. Confirm the service_name for the PDB by entering `lsnrctl status` or `lsnrctl services` from the command line. That should list the available service names on the system.

Comment: Doing that gives me 3 service names,
1) CLRExtProc
2) XE
3) XEXDB

When I enter these service name 
It throws error :
1) Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (for CLRExtProc)

2) Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied (for XEXDB/XE)

Comment: Is your PDB actually started? None of those service names is appropriate for the PDB.

Comment: Not sure if it means the same but i have tried altering the connection by typing these in cmd line,
1)sqlplus '/ as sysdba', 2) con_name (Shows CDB$ROOT. So i alter this in next step) 3) alter session set container=PDB$SEED; (Where session alters) 4) show con_name (shows con_name as PDB$SEED)

Do i need to anything else?

Comment: PDB$SEED is a read-only template for creating more PDBs. You can't use it for anything. `sqlplus / as sysdba` will only ever connect you to the container database (CDB$ROOT). To find out which other PDB database are available, you can list all of the available containers by connecting to the CDB and selecting from the `DBA_PDBS` view. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_mon.htm#ADMIN13933